# Reusing an old Facebook profile picture

Tags: facebook, profile-picture

On my Facebook account there is an automatically created photo album called "Profile Pictures" which contains all the images I've used as profile pictures in the past. I'd like to set one of these images to be my profile picture (not the one which is currently my profile picture, of course). Is there some way to do this without having to upload a new copy of the same image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Click your name or existing profile photo at the upper left corner of the screen to go into your profile.
2. Once there, the third or so item under your big profile pic at upper left should be "Photos".  Click on this.
3. Click on your "Profile Pictures" album.
4. Click on the photo you want to use as your profile picture.  It will expand into the centre of the screen with a bunch of stuff on the right.
5. In the upper right corner there are three icons, a gear, a downward arrowhead, and an X.  Click the gear icon.
6. A drop-down menu will appear.  The second-last item on the menu should be "Make Profile Picture".  Click on this.

After a few seconds you will be back at your profile screen, with the selected picture as your profile picture.

Answer (score 6):

If you are on timeline:

1. Go to your profile (timeline)
2. Mouseover your profile picture
3. Click on **Edit Profile Picture**
   [image]
4. Click **Choose from Photos**
   [image]
5. In the overlay, click **View Albums**
   [image]
6. Click on the album called **Profile Pictures**
7. Choose your image—this is it.

Comment: Or just bring up the photo and click on "Make Profile Picture".  (If you are looking at the photo in the theater mode this choice is in the gear menu.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm actually not using Timeline so I'm really looking for an answer that addresses that case.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky you will soon. It will become default in the near future.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but that's not what prompted me to ask the question.